# Erro em import do chatterbot

Tags: python, packages, chatbot, import, chatterbot

Usando o manual do biblioteca `chatterbot` tentei fazer um chatbot simples, porém, quando mando rodar no console do `pycharm` aparece o seguinte erro:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'

Também está dando problema nas linhas que eu marquei com um #

Esse é o código do chatterbot:

```
# -*- encodding: utf-8 -*-
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot import ChatBot

bot = ChatBot('Futaba', read_only=True)
conversa = ['Oi', 'Olá', 'Hey!', 'E aí!']

bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer) #
bot.train(conversa) #

while True:
    quest = input('Você')
    response = bot.get_response(quest)
    if float(response.confident) > 0.5:
        print('Futaba', response)
    else:
        print('Eu não entendi.')
```

Esse é todo o erro que aparece: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou intalar o modulo pytz? comando: `pip install pytz`

Comment: Tentei, resolveu esse problema, mas apareceu esse: AttributeError: 'ChatBot' object has no attribute 'set_trainer'